# Problem when trying to update the object of a React state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am making a Todo app. I am trying to give the completed button the ability to change the value of "state" in the object located in the React state from false to true whenever it is clicked. i am not sure how to go about with the handleChange function.

```
import { useState } from "react";

import "./App.css";

function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState([]);

  const [todosText, setTodosText] = useState("");

  function handleOnChange(e) {
    setTodosText(e.target.value);
  }

  function handleAdd() {
    setTodos((prevState) => {
      return [...prevState, { text: todosText, status: false }];
    });
  }

  function handleOnSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }

  function handleChange() {}

  const showText = todos.map((txt) => (
    <li key={txt.text} className={!txt.status ? "" : "dark"}>
      <span>{txt.text}</span>
      <button onClick={handleChange}>Completed</button>
      
    </li>
  ));

  console.log(todos);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>ToDo list</h1>
      <form onSubmit={handleOnSubmit}>
        <input type="text" name="todoItem" onChange={handleOnChange} />
        <button onClick={handleAdd}>Add</button>
      </form>
      <ul>{showText}</ul>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: `<button onClick={handleChange()}>` should be `<button onClick={handleChange}>` without the parenthesis.

Comment: oh ok, i am mostly having issues figuring out how to make the function  make the changes to the object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your id with your todo list id and if both matches then make your status `true` else return same todo object.

There is no unique identifier in your todo so I added it, please refer the codesanbox

```
function handleChange(id) {
  setTodos((prevState) =>
    prevState.map((todo) =>
      todo.id === id ? { ...todo, status: true } : todo
    )
  );
}
```

Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-wright-lomhuc?file=/src/App.js:453-615

Comment: Just updated my code. Thanks for the help this helped with my issue, so having a unique identifier makes it easier to update objects in an array?

Comment: having unique id in array of object is good practice because you need to pass it as `key` while looping and you can also identify it correctly, as I do to complete the todo.